# Aorus x570 Elite motherboard and cpu/gpu

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, gpu, amd-ryzen

I have n Aorus x570 elite motherboard, with a Ryzen 7 2700 processor and GeForce GTX 1070 graphics card.

I somehow thought I had a Ryzen 2 because of the 2700, so I bought a Ryzen 5600x and ordered a RTX 3070 GPU.

I have no idea what to do, would installing the Ryzen 5 5600x with the 3070 be a downgrade from my Ryzen 7 2700?

Or should I keep the Ryzen 7 2700 and install the RTX 3070 to it?

When I was looking at the gigabyte website, it stated the most compatible with the x570 was the 5000 series, yet I have a 7 2700 installed.

Comment: What is the problem or question? Your budget and needs defines your options. If you purchased these recently you can return those that do not work for you. It seems like you're asking for help making a decision that is mostly about preference and facts you already know.

Answer (score 0):

The only actually asked question is: "would installing the Ryzen 5 5600x with the 3070 be a downgrade from my Ryzen 7 2700?"

The answer to that is no. It is not a downgrade, it is an upgrade.

But that is technically answering the question, what really is important is 'is this upgrade worth it for me?', and we cannot answer that.

We can compare them though

```
Ryzen 7 2700                      Ryzen 5 5600x
Zen 1+ (2018) 12nm                zen 3     7nm
8 core                            6 core 
DDR-4 2933MHz                     DD4-3200MHz
PCI-E 3                           PCI-e v4
65W  (105W for the 2700X)         65W
CPU mark 15,735                   CPU mark 21941
```

Number will vary a bit, and using the 5600X with slower memory might drop performce. But it is faster. 6 more modern cores will beat the 8 older ones.

But as long as you are not limited during gaming by the CPU, then an upgrade is not important. So run your favourite games. If the CPU is at or near max, the upgrade likely makes sense. If not, return it and keep the money.

Lets move on from PCI performace to other features. The Aorus x570 elite motherboard supports PCI-e version 4, so the new CPU also has that, so you can then use the faster interface to things like NVME drives, graphics card etc.  That might be a good reason to upgrade if you add a graphics card which can use substanceially more bandwith than PCI-e 3 x 16 can deliver. This does not seem to be the case for a RTX 3070. So no need to upgrade here either.

My recommendation:

- No need to upgrade **for gaming**.
- New CPU will be more future proof, and it is faster. Choose with your wallet on money vs performance.